# Why is interface in React useful?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was learning Typescript's interface and its use in React. Moreover, as I found out(I hope I am correct:)), interface( used, for example, for prop) is needed to ensure that we can pass only certain props defined in interface prop. The question is what is the benefit of the use of interfaces to serve as kinda "Protection" to be not able to pass any props.

Comment: This question kinda boils down to the usefulness of a static type system at all. Answers to that are very opinionated, some find it useful to get guidance during coding, others think that 100% duck typing is a win. I suggest to read into types and type systems in general and what they can achieve. Also how JS without TS fits into this, then decide whether TS is useful for you or not. Within react it can be a great help, once you get down to redux it gets more awkward...

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to ensure that your components always get the right prop types.

It can also serve as documentation for other developers so they will know what props to pass to your components.

Comment: I meant prop types - data types. E.g. if you want array and not an object

Comment: sorry Victor, is it true that the whole idea behind Typescript is to be explicit and in turn help us achieve kinda protection?

Comment: I think so - and also documentation. See https://www.valentinog.com/blog/typescript/#TypeScript_tutorial_for_beginners_why_TypeScript